# Making multiple coloured line segment in Python according to a list of integers coding for a specific color

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I want to make a line segment with multiple colours according to the input of colour codes given as the list of integers. For example, suppose there is a list of integers n and tuple containing colour code

```
n= [1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 3]

codes=([1, 'Red'], [2, 'Yellow'], [3, 'Green'], [4, 'Blue'])
```

Then, I want a line segment which is made up of multiple colours according to the colour codes in the sequence of the given integers. Please find this image for reference

[image]

The given image has input sequence length of about 100 integers and corresponding colour codes. How can something like this be constructed?

Comment: Have you attempted anything?

Comment: what are you using to display (any) color: Tk, HTML, etc? More details on your environment and what you've tried would help narrow the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good solution for this sort of thing in python is the PIL library:

**Code:**

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

def colored_bar(data, colors, height=10, width=5):
    # Create a blank image
    im = Image.new('RGBA', (width * len(data), height), (0, 0, 0, 0))

    # Create a draw object
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)

    for i, val in enumerate(data):
        draw.rectangle((i * width, 0, (i+1) * width, height),
                       fill=colors[val])
    return im
```

**Test Code:**

```
n = [1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 3]
codes = dict(([1, 'red'], [2, 'yellow'], [3, 'green'], [4, 'blue']))

image = colored_bar(n, codes)
image.show()
```

**Results:**

[image]